# How to detect when a user has finished to watch a YouTube video embedded on your page?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I have a youtube video and I need to trigger an event when it is finished. Do you know how?

Comment: Check out: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Adding_event_listener

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when the API or the video was loaded you will able to see the state of the videos , here are those:
"-1" - video is ready to play
"1" - the video is playing (it clicked the play button)
"2" - the video is paused
"0" - end of the video

```
var status = player.getPlayerState();
```

[API YOUTUBE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)